# obtain Windows 10 Display settings values in Java

Tags: java

When user change Display settings scaling (Windows 10, right click on desktop, select Display settings and scale to 150%), suddenly all values reported by

```
GraphicsDevice device = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getDevice();
    Rectangle bounds = device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
```

or

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

or

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
```

become invalid. Is there a way how to get the actual values ?

Comment: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna looks like your best option there. It offers access to the native windows api with most dll's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution that seems to respect the Display settings.

```
javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D r = new javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D(0, 0, 1, 1);
ObservableList<Screen> screens = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(r);
if (screens != null && screens.size() > 0) {
    javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D rc = screens.get(0).getBounds();
}
```